# Codesign Check Fails . Code Object is not Signed at all In architecture: armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign, armv7

I ran the application on my test device iPod Touch 3G with iOS5.0.1 (9A405).  The app complies and run fine on the real device.  I have developer account installed.  I get following error:

error: Codesign check fails : /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-03-12/AppName 3-12-12 9.58 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: armv7.

I assume the my iPod Touch is a armv6 device. But in the AppName-Info.Plist

I have following fields:
Architectures         Standard(armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
Base SDK              Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)

Code Signing Entitlements
  Debug
  Release
Code Signing Identity  iPhone Developer
  Debug                iPhone Developer
    Any iOS SDK        iPhone Developer
  Release              iPhone Developer
    Any iOS SDK        iPhone Developer

One extra thing, in the
CODE_SIGN_REQUIRED is set to NO in /Platform/iPhoneOS.Platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Developer/SDKSettings.plist.  I cannot seems to change it to YES. I copy that file to desktop. Change the field and drop it back to this location.  This field will not update even when Xcode Version 4.2.1 (4D502) is closed.

EDIT: I updated this file via command line. I was able to change CODE_SIGN_REQUIRED to YES but the problem still persist.

```
    <dict>
    <key>AlternateSDK</key>
    <string>iphonesimulator5.0</string>
    <key>CanonicalName</key>
    <string>iphoneos5.0</string>
    <key>CustomProperties</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>DefaultProperties</key>
    <dict>
            <key>AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED</key>
            <string>NO</string>
            <key>CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED</key>
            <string>YES</string>
```

Do i need to unable the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS from blank to YES? Please help.

Why is it so hard to do code sign in Xcode? I had a app released on Android app store. It was much easier.